# Как (чем) поймать ошибку (проект C++)?

Tags: c++, windows

Есть проект - изначально представляющий собой прошивку для устройства, написан на С++. Из него сделана dll - которая получает данные, обрабатывает, возвращает результат. Проект dll сделан в Visual Studio 2015.

Теперь проблема: собранный вариант работает на моем компе, но не работает на других компах (виснет при обращении к dll). Исключений не возникает. В режиме отладки при выходе из dll студия выдает ошибку - Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'idxOfStrSize' was corrupted. Если нажать "Продолжить" - то данные приходят корректные, работа продолжается.

Видимо где-то происходит запись в область, для этого не предназначенную, но вот где? Объем кода - 30к+ строк. Как и чем можно найти это место (места)?

Comment: Вопрос вида "как устранять баги в программах" слишком общий.

Comment: Приведите хотя бы код связанный с idxOfStrSize.